# Can I apply polymeric sand only on a x inches wide stretch where the patio joins the wall?

Tags: patio

I am in the process of regrading my patio. I had a wet wall problem because the patio was sloped toward the house. I want to make sure that no water gets near the wall again, even with the correct slope applied.
For this I would like to apply polymeric sand on a strip of let's say 3 foot where the patio joins the wall.

Is this a good idea?

Comment: What type of wall is the patio adjoining?

Comment: The foundation is concrete walls up to the grade level. Above that it seems to be cinder blocks up the the main floor level. This is a bungalow with above the grade basement windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to put 3 foot strip in width of polymeric sand over existing pavers? You will be OK with how that would look? I am just not sure how well such a strip will stay together over the long haul.

I sure wouldn't do it, I would bite the bullet and pull up the pavers then regrade the base away from the house and put the pavers back.

Comment: I have already done that but not I want to make sure there is no way my wall gets water again, not even the minimal infiltration when the water gets through the joints between the pavers. Yes probably the polymeric sand is not a good idea if it is not applied for the entire patio...

Comment: If you have already graded away from your house, then not much should get in. But some still could. I think the best way to really keep it out would be a moisture barrier over your outside wall extending down a foot or so from the top of your pavers.

Comment: Yes I think that this is the solution. Any idea what I could use for that?

Answer (score 1):

Polymeric sand is to lock paver joints. It's not waterproof any more than concrete (less so, even).

So if the intent is to use it as a waterproofer along your wall, it won't do much.